# How to use blade variables inside Alpine.js directives?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

I have the following component:

```php
<div x-data="{ rating: @entangle('rating'), hover: 0 }">
    @for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
        <x-heroicon-s-star
            x-on:click="rating = {{ $i }}"
            x-on:mouseover="hover = {{ $i }}"
            x-on:mouseout="hover = 0"
            class="star w-8 h-8 cursor-pointer"
            :class="(rating >= {{ $i }} && rating != 0) || hover >= {{ $i }} ? 'text-yellow-500' : 'text-gray-300'"
        />
    @endfor
    <input type="hidden" x-bind:value="rating" name="rating">
</div>
```

but I'm getting

```
syntax error, unexpected token "{"
```

for

```
x-on:click="rating = {{ $i }}"
                     ^
---------------------|
```

How can I use blade variables inside alpine?

What I want to accomplish is 5 stars and when I hover e.g. the 3rd star, all stars up to the 3rd star are yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the problem is there.

Since you are using a Blade component, I suppose that the Alpine *:class* object is grabbed by Blade before, making confusion with the syntax.

You can try doubling the colon to escape it to allow the Alpine code to reach the browser:

```
<x-heroicon-s-star
   x-on:click="rating = {{ $i }}"
   x-on:mouseover="hover = {{ $i }}"
   x-on:mouseout="hover = 0"
   class="star w-8 h-8 cursor-pointer"
   ::class="(rating >= {{ $i }} && rating != 0) || hover >= {{ $i }} ? 'text-yellow-500' : 'text-gray-300'"
/>
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#escaping-attribute-rendering) the documentation